# Moshi PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm using Moshi for an Android App, but when the payload change for any reason, example: the backend add a new object type, the app will crash because I need to tell Moshi to get this new object type.

```
return Moshi.Builder()
    .add(Adapter1())
    .add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory
            .of(BaseClass::class.java, "baseclass")
            .withSubtype(EntityOne::class.java, "entityone")
            .withSubtype(EntityTwo::class.java, "entitytwo")
    )
    .build()
```

All works well, but if a new entity is coming inside the payload, the app won't show any data.

Example: an "entitythree" is added, to avoid the app stop showing info, I need to come and add

```
.withSubtype(EntityThree::class.java, "entitythree")
```

How can I avoid this behaviour, if the payload add new entities, nothing happen and the app will continue working well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a class denoting an unknown entity:

```
data class UnknownEntity : BaseClass {
    val baseclass: String = "unknown"
}
```

Then, add to your factory:

```
PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory
            .of(BaseClass::class.java, "baseclass")
            .withSubtype(EntityOne::class.java, "entityone")
            .withSubtype(EntityTwo::class.java, "entitytwo")
            .withDefaultValue(UnknownEntity())
```

Then in the rest of your logic, where you manipulate with the acquired entities, just ignore the `UnknownEntity` instances, and the app should work as before.